# Minimal size of share in Shamir's Sharing Scheme

Tags: encryption, secret-sharing

Why does the combined shared key in Adi Shamir's Sharing Scheme have to be smaller or equal than each secret share?

Comment: What do you mean by 'shared key'?  With secret sharing, everyone gets a share, but those obviously aren't shared.

Comment: Basically, the question is:
The size of each share is less than or equal to the size of the secret D. Why?

Comment: 'The size of each share is less than or equal to the size of the secret;' that is not true; each share is an effectively random field element (and hence takes up that much storage); the shared secret generated is also a field element (but not necessarily a random one; hence the amount of storage required might be less)

Comment: Maybe the question was written in a wrong way.
I am talking about the first property here:
https://cs.jhu.edu/~sdoshi/crypto/papers/shamirturing.pdf
There are four of them

Answer (score 1):

As listed by Shamir, the first property is:

```
(1) The size of each piece does not exceed the size of the original data.
```

Here's what he means; there's a public value $p$; the original data is encoded as a value between 0 and $p-1$.  In addition, the secret portion of each share ('piece')  is a value between 0 and $p-1$, hence the size of each piece does not exceed the size of the original data.

What Shamir meant is that the scheme doesn't expand the share size beyond the size of the representation of the secret.  It can be shown that if the share size is smaller than the representation of the secret, then someone with $k-1$ shares (where $k$ is the threshold) can deduce some information about the secret (at the very least, some values which the secret cannot be).  Hence, Shamir's method is optimal in this sense.

Comment: Thanks! 
Another question is how it is possible to delete a share without changing other shares?